# How to change qwebview's background image, color and font color

Tags: qt, qwebview, qwebkit

I want to change my webview's background image, color and font color. I tried setBackgroundRole method but it only have few color. It doesn't have the color that I want. And I don't find how to set font color and background image. Do you have any ideas to solve this thing?

Answer (score 0):

Use html for that, QWebView is just a container for QWebPage, where you can set all you need in page's html code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it's not that I want. Ex: I want when I load some text to Qwebview, the text will use my color to display and it will display on my background.

Answer (score 0):

Use `QWidget::setPalette()` to set your own `QPalette`. With this you can freely choose colors for each role.

To have an image as a background you would have to derive your own class from `QWebView` and override `paintEvent()` I think.

Comment: `QPalette p = ui->webView->palette();
    QPixmap pixmap1("D:/duc2.jpg");
    QRect rect = ui->webView->rect();
    QSize size(rect.width() , rect.height());
    QPixmap pixmap(pixmap1.scaled(size));
    p.setBrush(QPalette::Background,  pixmap);
    ui->webView->setPalette(p);` This is my code to set webview's background but I don't see my background image on webview. Is there something wrong ?

Comment: Looks like it might work. Did you use setBackgroundRole() in addition somewhere? Although I think it should still work: QPalette::Background is deprecated, QPalette::Window is the new enum for it.

Comment: `ui->webView->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Window);` I used setBackgroundRole() method like that. I also modified it `ui->webView->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Background);` but it didn't work. What can I do to solve this thing?

Comment: Yeah, it seems QWebView is a bit different than most QWidgets. I did not manage to put background picture via the QPalette in it either. I think best bet would be something like this: http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2009/06/30/transparent-qwebview-or-qwebpage/ and have your picture underneath in a different widgets.

Answer (score 0):

use setHtml function

```
QString htmlhead = "<head><style>body {\n   background-color: #eee;\nbackground-image: url("+QUrl("qrc:/new/prefix1/back.png").toString()+");";
ui->webView->setHtml(htmlhead);
```